# How to find lists after a specific word

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to find all lists after words which i want to categories according to that word.

So my sample data is as following:

```
<p>
    <a href="#">WordA</a>
</p>
<ul>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
<ul>
<p>
    <a href="#">WordB</a>
</p>
<ul>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
<ul>
```

Taken the example above into account i want ti fetch `WordA` and categories that to the list below it, and the same for `WordB`.

Is it somehow possible to search `WordA` and look for the `<ul>` tag below it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over all links in paragraphs, for every link get the parent's next sibling `ul` tag and get all `li` tags inside ([`find_next_sibling()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling) helps with getting the next `ul` element after the paragraph):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div>
    <p>
        <a href="#">WordA</a>
    </p>
    <ul>
        <li>Something</li>
        <li>Something</li>
    </ul>
    <p>
        <a href="#">WordB</a>
    </p>
    <ul>
        <li>Something</li>
        <li>Something</li>
    </ul>
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for a in soup.select('p > a'):
    print a.text

    for li in a.parent.find_next_sibling('ul').find_all('li'):
        print li.text
    print "-----"
```

prints:

```
WordA
Something
Something
-----
WordB
Something
Something
-----
```